# Importing Excel in Watson Studio

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read an excel file (xlsx) into a data frame in ibm watson studio. the excel file is saved in my list of assets. i'm a bit new to python

i have tried creating a project token with some help i got here. I will appreciate if someone helps with the complete code.

i tried this

```
from project_lib import Project
project = Project(project_id='', 
project_access_token='')
pc = project.project_context
file = project.get_file("xx.xlsx")
file.sheet_names
df = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df = file.parse (0)
df.head ()
```

i needed to pass the excel file into a pandas data frame , pd for eg.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

1. First insert the project token as you already did.
2. Then simply fetch file and then do .seek(0),
3. Then read it using pandas' read_excel() and you should be able to read it.

`# Fetch the file`

`my_file = project.get_file("tests-example.xls")`

```
# Read the CSV data file from the object storage into a pandas DataFrame
my_file.seek(0)
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel(my_file, nrows=10)
```

[image]

For more information:- https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/project-lib-python.html